# SQL Best way to store "Check All That Apply" in survey

Tags: sql

I have a survey that ask the question of availability via check boxes like so:

```
I am available (please check all that apply:
[] Early Mornings
[] Mid Mornings
[] Early Afternoons
[] Mid Afternoons
[] Evenings
[] Late Evenings
[] Overnight
```

That I need to translate into a SQL database. My question is: What is the best way to store this data under one column? I was thinking of a 7 digit bit storage like: 0010001 (Indicates the candidate is only available during Early Afternoons and overnight). Is there a better way? Thanks for any opinions!

Comment: Not sure what the right term is here but why not assign each choice a 2^n value, 1,2,4,8... and store the sum of them. Then you can use bitwise operators to check what is selected and you're not restricted to seven choices if the requirements change.

Comment: Make a separate table "TimesOfDay" and store id of selected item in your column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A separate table for the options and a "join table" of options to the candidate. The other solutions/suggestions will impede data integrity and performance in a relational database. If you've got another DB it might be different but don't do anything other than the relational table if you're using SQL.

Comment: +1 This is clearly the best way of doing this, although it doesn't technically answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason the results need to be stored inside one column? If so, <strike>your solution is probably the best way</strike> **EDIT: If you are going to be querying this data your solution is the best way, otherwise follow the other answer using "|" to separate the strings in one long varchar field**, though anyone looking at that data is going to have no clue what it means unless they've taken the time to memorize each question in order.

If it doesn't need to be all in one column I'd recommend just creating a column for each question with a bit value similar to what you already want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe delimited flags.

Make the column a fairly wide text column, then store:

```
'Early Mornings|Evenings|Overnight'
```

if those 3 choices were selected.

(Note: I do agree with the other answer that it is likely better to use separate columns, but this is how I'd do it if there were a good reason to want just 1 column)